# How to select name and get value from <ul><li> with xpath?

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm looking for an easier way to select a value after a name in an html ul li string.

Data is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="custom_options/custom_option/value" />
Result: <ul><li><strong>Breedte (mm):</strong> 2080</li><li><strong>Hoogte (mm) incl. Kast:</strong> 1420</li><li><strong>Kastmaat:</strong> 150</li><li><strong>Type kast:</strong> Afgeschuind</li><li><strong>Kastkleur:</strong> RAL 6009 Spargroen</li></ul>
```

Now I use a substring solution.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(custom_options/custom_option/value, 'Breedte&#32;&#40;mm&#41;:&lt;/strong&gt;'), '&lt;/li&gt;')"/>

<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(custom_options/custom_option/value, 'Type&#32;kast:&lt;/strong&gt;'), '&lt;/li&gt;')"/>
```

I would like an xpath solution like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Breedte (mm):" /> 2080
<xsl:value-of select="@Type kast:" /> Afgeschuind
```

I am using xsl 1.0

Comment: Please post an example of the input and the exact result you expect: see: [mcve]. It seems that the HTML within your XML is escaped - which means there will be no simple solution in XSLT 1.0 (or 2.0)

Comment: It is not clear to me how your input looks, if that is XML or XHTML or escaped XHTML. Anyway, if it is escaped XHTML and you want to apply XPath, you first need to parse the XHTML with an XML parser, in XSLT 3/XPath 3.1 this is possible with the `parse-xml` and/or `parse-xml-fragment` function, with an XSLT 1.0 processor it will depend entirely on the processor's platform and API whether you can expose a similar function directly to XPath/XSLT.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor exactly do you use? How exactly do you use it (e.g. writing code in C# or Python or PHP or Java) or just from the command line or even embedded in some tool?

Comment: Its use in an Magento extension https://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/magento-order-export-module.html<!--
    XSLT Version = 1.0
    XSLT Vendor = libxslt
    XSLT Vendor URL = http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/-->

Comment: While libxslt, when called from a Python or PHP API, usually allows you to call into Python or PHP to parse some string as XML into nodes, such an option is usually not available if the XSLT processor is somehow embedded into a tool. Ask the xtento support whether they know a way to do what you want or whether you can set up a pipeline of two transformations where the first uses e.g. disable-output-escaping to output the escaped markup and the second then uses normal XSLT/XPath processing.

Answer (score -1):

I would use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//ul/li/text()[preceding-sibling::strong='Breedte (mm):']"/>
```

and this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//ul/li/text()[preceding-sibling::strong='Type kast:']"/>
```

Comment: The use of e.g. `substring-before(substring-after(custom_options/custom_option/value, 'Breedte&#32;&#40;mm&#41;:&lt;/strong&gt;'), '&lt;/li&gt;')` in the original code seems to suggest the `ul/li/strong` content is not parsed as XML but is somehow only available as plain text (e.g. escaped in a CDATA section) so it seems unlikely that XPath selection based on elements/nodes can be done before parsing the plain text into nodes.